# I am trying to rename all my image file in the dir, but getting this error OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

```
import os 
path ='/Users/kunalmalhotra/Desktop/HotdogNotHotdog/hotdog/' 
for filename in os.listdir(path):
       if filename.endswith(".jpg"):
           for filename in os.listdir(path):
               for i in range(0,100):
                   os.rename(filename, "hotdog"+str(i)+".jpg")
```

Comment: How about an explanation so we know what you are doing?  Format your code using four spaces and could you please mention the path you are sure and not just the code?

Comment: @simon, new to StackOverflow, still getting issues in formatting properly, but regarding the question I am trying to rename all the images in the folder but unable to do that and getting this getting this error OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
Ask Question

Comment: @Rakesh Thank you very very much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have some unwanted loops. Just use a counter flag to rename file as you required.

**Ex:**

```
import os 
path ='/Users/kunalmalhotra/Desktop/HotdogNotHotdog/hotdog/'
c = 0                                              #use flag as counter.
for filename in os.listdir(path):                  
    if filename.endswith(".jpg"):
        fileN = os.path.join(path, filename)
        fileToRename = os.path.join(path, "hotdog"+str(c)+".jpg")                          
        os.rename(fileN, fileToRename)   
        c += 1
```

Comment: Still the same issue, getting OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Comment: Updated snippet Can you try now?